# Oscillatory integral with absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value, oscillatory-integral

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to[0,+\infty)$ is a continuous function. Are there general conditions under which the following limit exists?

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 |\cos(nf(x))|dx$$

Obviously if $f$ is a constant that is not an integer multiple of $\pi$ the limit does not exist. Does the limit exist if $f'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$? If so, what if we drop differentiability and only require $f$  not be locally constant?

When $f$ is not differentiable, can one still show
$$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 |\cos(nf(x))|dx >0$$
under suitable conditions on $f$?

Comment: "if $f$ is constant the limit does not exist". This is not true. Suppose $f \equiv \pi$. Then $|\cos(nf)| \equiv 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the limit is $1$.

Comment: Thanks, but assume f is not pi.

Comment: More of a remark than anything: if instead of $[0,1]$ we take a different interval, we might get different answers. For instance, with $(0,1]$ and $f=\log$, the limit is $2/\pi$.

Comment: @Integrand I think we also get $2/\pi$ when $f:[0,1]\to[1,2]$ such that $f(x)=x^2+1$, here the range is different.

Answer (score 8):

**Proposition.** Let $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $f’(x)\ne 0$ for each $x\in [0,1]$. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 |\cos(nf(x))|dx=\tfrac {2}\pi.$

*Proof.* Since $f’$ is a continuous function on a compact set $[0,1]$, it is uniformly continuous and $\ell=\inf \{|f’(x)|:x\in [0,1]\}>0$. Fix any $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f’(x)$ is uniformly continuous, there exists a natural number $N$ such that
$|f’(y)-f’(x)|\le \varepsilon$ for any $x,y\in [0,1]$ such that  $|y-x|\le\tfrac \pi{N\ell}$.

Let $n\ge N$ be any natural number. Put $X_n=\left\{x\in [0,1]:nf(x)\in \tfrac \pi2+\pi\Bbb Z \right\}$. Since $\ell>0$, $f$ is strictly monotonic, so the set $X_n$ is finite.  Let $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_m$ be an enumeration of $X_n$. Put $x_0=0$ and $x_{m+1}=1$. Then $x_{i+1}-x_i\le\tfrac \pi{n\ell}$ for each $i=0,\dots m$. Put $I_i=\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |\cos(nf(x))|dx$.

Then $I=\int_0^1 |\cos(nf(x))|dx=\sum_{i=0}^m I_i$. Clearly, $|I_0|, |I_m|\le \tfrac \pi{n\ell}$. Let $i$ be any integer from $1$ to $m-1$. By Lagrange’s theorem there exists $z\in (x_i, x_{i+1})$ such that $\tfrac {f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)} {x_{i+1}-x_i}=f’(c)$. For each $y\in [x_i, x_{i+1}]$ put $g(y)=f(y)-f(x_i)-(y-x_i)f’(c).$ It is easy to check that $g(x_i)=0$ and for each $y$
$$|g’(y)|=|f’(y)-f’(c)|\le\varepsilon.$$
By Lagrange’s theorem, there exists $z\in (x_i, y)$ such that

$$|g(y)|=|g(y)-g(x_i)|=|g’(z)|(y-x_i) \le \varepsilon\frac \pi{n\ell}.$$ Again by  Lagrange’s theorem, there exists $d$ between $f(y)$ and $(f(x_i)+(y-x_i)f’(c))$ such that

$$|\cos (nf(y))-\cos n(f(x_i)+(y-x_i)f’(c))|=n|\sin nd|| f(y)- f(x_i)-(y-x_i)f’(c)|\le n |g(y)|\le \varepsilon\frac \pi{\ell}.$$

We have $|I_i- I_i’|\le I_i’’$, where $I’_i=\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |\cos n(f(x_i)+(y-x_i)f’(c))| dy $ and
$$I_i’’=\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |\cos (nf(y))-\cos n(f(x_i)+(y-x_i)f’(c))| dy\le \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \varepsilon\frac \pi{\ell} dy\le 
(x_{i+1}-x_i) \varepsilon\frac \pi{\ell}.$$

Let us calculate $I’_i$. We see that $h(y)=f(x_i)+(y-x_i)f’(c)$ is a linear function such that $h(x_i)=f(x_i)$ and
$$h(x_{i+1})= f(x_i)+(x_{i+1}-x_i)\tfrac {f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)} {x_{i+1}-x_i}=f(x_{i+1})=f(x_i)\pm \frac {\pi}n,$$
by the construction of the sequence $(x_j)$. Since the primitive of $\cos n h(y)$ is $\frac 1{n f’(c)}\sin n h(y)$, we have
$$I’_i=\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} |\cos n h(y)| dy=\left|\int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \cos n h(y) dy \right|= 
\left|\frac 1{n f’(c)}\sin n h(y){\Huge|}_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}}\right|=\left|\frac 2{n f’(c)}\right|=\frac {2(x_{i+1}-x_i)} {\pi}.$$

We have
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} I_i-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} I’_i\right|\le 
\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} \left| I_i- I’_i\right|\le \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} I’’_i\le \sum_{i=1}^{m-1}
(x_{i+1}-x_i) \varepsilon\frac \pi{\ell}=(x_{m}-x_1) \varepsilon\frac \pi{\ell}\le \varepsilon\frac \pi{\ell} .$$

But $$\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} I’_i=\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} \frac {2(x_{i+1}-x_i)} {\pi}=\frac {2(x_{m}-x_1)}{\pi}$$

Since $\varepsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small, and  $\left|  \frac {2(x_{m}-x_1)}{\pi}-\frac 2{\pi}\right|\le  \frac 2{\pi}\cdot \frac\pi{n\ell}=\frac 2{n\ell},$ the proposition follows. $\square$

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas about the non-differentiable case? I think that's the more interesting part of the question.

Comment: @Cantor I think we need other tools for this case. My answer was rather straightforward and can be the first step in an investigation of your question.

Comment: I haven't put much thought into this, but my guess as to a next direction would be to try to prove it for absolutely continuous functions with similar restrictions.

Comment: Or perhaps before that, we can see that functions in Alex's proof are strictly monotone, so maybe we can try strictly monotone continuous functions? The idea in both cases is basically to try to weaken continuous differentiability to something similar in the sense of measure.

Answer (score 3):

We can generalize and perhaps gain some insight. I'll start with a generalization of the Riemann Lebesgue lemma (GRLL):

GRLL: Suppose $g$ is continuous and periodic on $\mathbb R,$ with period $p>0.$ Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b].$ Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b g(nx)f(x)\,dx = \frac{\int_0^p g(x)\,dx }{p}\cdot\int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$

This is not too hard to prove; I'll omit the proof for now.

Corollary: Assume in addition that $f\in C^1[a,b]$ and $f'$ is nonzero in $[a,b].$ Then

$$\tag 1 \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b g(nf(x))\,dx = \frac{(b-a)}{p}\int_0^p g.$$

Proof: On the left side of $(1),$ let $x=f^{-1}(y).$ We get

$$\tag 2 \int_a^b g(nf(x))\,dx = \int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b)} g(ny)\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}\,dy.$$

Apply GRLL to the right side of $(2)$ to get

$$\tag 3\frac{\int_0^p g(x)\,dx }{p}\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b)}\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}\,dy.$$

Now let $y=f^{-1}(z)$ to see $(3)$ equals the right side of $(1).$ The proof of the Corollary is complete.

Let's compare this result with Alex Ravsky's, where we have $g(y)=|\cos y|$ and $a=0,b=1.$ Here $g$ has period $\pi.$ The Corollary gives

$$\frac{1-0}{\pi}\int_0^\pi |\cos x|\,dx =  \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot 2 = \frac{2}{\pi}$$

for the answer, which agrees with Ravsky.

I believe we can extend these results further: Again suppose $f\in C^1$ but this time we assume only $m(\{x\in [a,b]: f'(x)=0\})=0.$ Then we get the same answer:

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b g(nf(x))\,dx = \frac{(b-a)}{p}\int_0^p g.$$

I'll leave this unproven at the moment as time is slipping by.

Comment: $\liminf|\cos(Cn)|>0$?!

Comment: Ah ... bad mistake there. It seems I mixed  up $\liminf$ with $\limsup.$ Thanks, will delete that part for now. (The only thing that was correct in that part was "I'm far from answering this".)